# Why can I not copy file with cp -rf mydir/* .../mydir/.?

Tags: cp

When I try to copy `cp -rf mydir/* .../mydir/.` I get next error:

`cp: cannot stat 'mydir/*': No such file or directory`

But there are files in this directory.

Please help me to find out reason of it.

Comment: There's no such thing as `.../` did you mean `../`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the shell cannot find anything to expand `*` into, then it leaves it untouched. So if there are no files or directories in `mydir` (except hidden/dot files/directories), then `mydir/*` is passed as it is to `cp`. And `cp` cannot find any file called `mydir/*`, as the error says.

For example:

```
$ ls /srv -l
total 0
$ ls /srv/*
ls: cannot access /srv/*: No such file or directory
```

Unless you're trying to exclude hidden files and folders you should simply do:

```
cp -r mydir ../
```